# Update two columns in MySQL from select statement

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update two columns in MySQL:

```
update table1
set (table1.score, table1.count) = 
(select (table2.maxScore - table2.score ) as diff, count(*)
from table2
where (table2.maxScore - table2.score) <= 600
and table2.age > 50
group by diff);
```

But, MySQL does not support this syntax.  I've seen some examples using JOIN, but I can't make it work here.  Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `(Analytics.GN_recency_max_score - Analytics.GN_recency_score) diff`, Is it two columns or you meant `(Analytics.GN_recency_max_score - Analytics.GN_recency_score) AS diff`

Comment: Yes, you are correct:  AS diff. For some reason, the AS is not required. MySQL executes that select statement (outside of the UPDATE) correctly.

Comment: I cleaned up my original SQL because it was pretty hard to follow.

Comment: Excuse me, But in your `set (table1.score, table1.count)`, I don't think it is possible to `SET` two columns at once, But you can go with `table1.score = ..., table1.count = ...`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: No, it is possible to set two columns at once. The syntax I have works in most other databases, just not in MySQL. No one seems to know how to change the syntax for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  MySQL can definitely update more than one column at once.  I needed to change my original query because MySQL requires using JOIN with ON when updating more than one column.  To prove it, I added an extra column "secondCol" to my example.  I have looked all over the web for this, and never found the answer.  I hope this helps some people.

```
 update table1 join
 (select (table2.maxScore - table2.score ) as diff, count(*) as count
 from table2
 where (table2.maxScore - table2.score) <= 600
 and table2.age > 50
 group by diff) as scores
 on table1.count = scores.count
 set table1.score = scores.diff, table1.secondCol = scores.count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should SET their values separately,

```
UPDATE scoresUniverse 
SET scoreUniver.GNfemScore = (Analytics.GN_recency_max_score - Analytics.GN_recency_score ),
ScoresUniverse.GNfemCount = (Select count(*) from Analytics.GN_recency_score where (Analytics.PR_recency_max_score - Analytics.PR_recency_score) <= 600 and Analytics.Older_female_50 > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn’t include the GROUP BY diff. This is a tricky select:  I get the score for everyone in this demographic, group the scores, and the COUNT(*) tells me how many are in each score group. We can’t split up the select.

Comment: I cleaned up my original SQL because it was hard to follow.